# Self-Contact Topology Errors?

Tags: coordinate-system, geometry, error, topology, qgis-3

I've been trying to clean up some vector data sets so that I can reproject them to WGS84 but I keep finding topological errors that fail the process. The one error I can't resolve involves a node on a polygon that shared by more than two (2) of that polygon's edges. For example:

[image]

Ideally, I would want to remove these types of topology errors so that I can reproject the shapefile but the QGIS 3 "Check Geometries" tool doesn't offer any suggestions on how to do it. I'm wondering what the best course of action is for these situations and if there is a tool/method that works best for these situations.

Comment: Could you add one such polygon as WKT into your question?

Comment: The solution depends on whether the two lines cross each other, or simply share a vertex. In the second case, you can simply move one of the vertices using the vertex editor.

Comment: @Will: I'm afraid that it's not so easy to give additional advice as long as we don't have more details. It really depends on the very case: so what works in one instance might not work in another context.

Comment: If it's a "banana" polygon, you can try a buffer at 0.

Comment: Have you tried the Vector geometry - Fix geometries tool?  What method are you using to reproject your data that runs into a geometry error and halts?  If you use Export features and change the CRS to WGS 84 does that work?

Answer (score 5):

There are quite a few automated tools for checking and repairing geometries in QGIS. The question is - why are they invalid in the first place? It may be helpful to go back upstream to figure out why this is happening. Often, we may not have the time or people may be unaware of how those invalid geometries come up.  It is often better to inspect the individual geometries to verify visually what is going on and you can manually repair geometries in QGIS.

That said, you may just want an automated solution.

In **QGIS** there are a few automated tools:

**To check for invalid geometries:**

**Vector Geometries --> Check Validity**

[image]

This will show you were any invalid geometries are located and what is causing them. You can then zoom into any area and edit the geometries to fix

**To automate fixing geometries**:

1. One method is to use a **Buffer** value of 0 or a really small number like 0.0001. This may resolve *some* geometry issues.
2. Vector Geometries --> **Fix Geometries** tool
   [image]
3. GRASS --> Vector --> **v.clean**
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, in this instance, it's publicly available shapefiles from my local government. :/   In my instance, creating a small buffer fixed nearly all of them for me but awarding the points for the other solutions as well. (mapshaper's clean parameter also worked on for me as well!)

Comment: @Will might be worth emailing their department! Typically these accumulate because boundaries do not always align properly or topology rules aren't defined.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried uploading your data to **MapShaper**?:

https://mapshaper.org/

It has an option to fix topology issues:

https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Topology-Issues